# I cant center contents of a div

Tags: css

I have a script that gets 9 results from a mysql query. I then add the results in php to $show_status . When I output the results I cant get them all centered?

I print results like so:

```
<div class="col-md-4 centered">Latest news<?echo $show_status ?></div>
```

The Latest news is centered but the $show_status results are on the left?

The code to get the results is

```
<?

include 'db.php';
$result = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT * FROM status ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 9');

$date = array();
$person = array();
$type = array();
$status = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $date[] = $row['date']; 
    $person[] = $row['person'];
    $type[] = $row['type'];
    $status[] = $row['status'];

    }


$show_status = "<div style='height: 88px;' id='news-container'>
<ul style='padding: 0pt; top: 0px;'>

<li style='margin: 0pt; padding: 0pt; height: 58px; font-size:10px; display: list-item;'>
<div>
<span style='font-size: 14px !important; color: #333638 !important;'>$date[1] $type[1]</span><BR>$person[1] $status[1]<BR>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li style='margin: 0pt; padding: 0pt; height: 58px; font-size:10px; display: list-item;'>
<div>
<span style='font-size: 14px !important; color: #333638 !important;'>$date[2] $type[2]</span><BR>$person[2] $status[2]<BR>
            </div>
        </li>

    <li style='margin: 0pt; padding: 0pt; height: 58px; font-size:10px; display: list-item;'>
            <div>
<span style='font-size: 14px !important; color: #333638 !important;'>$date[3] $type[3]</span><BR>$person[3] $status[3]<BR>
            </div>
        </li><li style='margin: 0pt; padding: 0pt; height: 58px; font-size:10px; display: list-item;'>
            <div>
<span style='font-size: 14px !important; color: #333638 !important;'>$date[4] $type[4]</span><BR>$person[4] $status[4]<BR>
            </div>
        </li><li style='margin: 0pt; padding: 0pt; height: 58px; font-size:10px;'>
            <div>
<span style='font-size: 14px !important; color: #333638 !important;'>$date[5] $type[5]</span><BR>$person[5] $status[5]<BR>
            </div>
        </li>
<li style='margin: 0pt; padding: 0pt; height: 58px; font-size:10px;'>
            <div>
<span style='font-size: 14px !important; color: #333638 !important;'>$date[6] $type[6]</span><BR>$person[6] $status[6]<BR>
            </div>
        </li>
<li style='margin: 0pt; padding: 0pt; height: 58px; font-size:10px;'>
            <div>
<span style='font-size: 14px !important; color: #333638 !important;'>$date[7] $type[7]</span><BR>$person[7] $status[7]<BR>
            </div>
        </li>
<li style='margin: 0pt; padding: 0pt; height: 58px; font-size:10px;'>
            <div>
<span style='font-size: 14px !important; color: #333638 !important;'>$date[8] $type[8]</span><BR>$person[8] $status[8]<BR>
            </div>
        </li>       

        </ul>
</div>";

?>
```

and the CSS is :

```
#news-container
{
    width: auto; 
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: auto;
    border: 0px solid #ffffff;
    text-align:center;
}

#news-container ul li div
{
    width: auto; 
    border: 0px solid #a8a7a7;
    background: #a8a7a7;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Thanks in advance, its doing my head in!

Comment: You really shouldn't use in-line styles like this

Comment: Try `<div class="col-md-4 text-center">` instead of `<div class="col-md-4 centered">` and i totally agree with @grumpy, your CSS should be within the CSS file and thats it.

Comment: The issue at hand doesn't seem to be at all related to PHP, though, so I would recommend removing that tag. I would also recommend not echoing big chunks of HTML. Add an end php-tag `?>`, add the html and then an open php-tag again `<?php` . Then it will be much easier to read and maintain + your IDE will most likely be able to syntax highlight the HTML.

Comment: Also, I was able to cut the size of your code IN HALF with a foreach-loop, which also makes it easier to not make simple typographical mistakes etc

Comment: I appreciate that GrumpCrouton but can you show me this half of code please. Thats not really my issue, its the centering of the results!

Comment: @zak, I've already given you the answer to this problem read up..

Comment: that was rather entertaining .. erm .. @zak - try making your own CSS, instead of relying on twitter-bootstrap; so in your css you could always create a class like so: `.centered{margin:auto; text-align:center;}`

Comment: @argon "Don't use the CSS framework that you are using to do your css"? It's always bad to write new css code when it's already written in your framework.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton huh? nope I don't use frameworks (at all) I had enough of those, not only CSS but JS, PHP, NodeJS, Python, C, etc as well. The problem is they clash and you spend more time bug-fixing than developing.

Comment: @argon, does this mean you make your own Laravel / Symfony structure too? ^_^

Comment: Indeed, I made my very own PHP framework also, beats the crap out of many popular ones regarding simplicity, flexibility, functionality, portability, rapid-development and speed-of-code :D

Comment: I'll take your word for that. I'm quite content with using Laravel / Symfony / Bootstrap etc. I used to prefer custom building too until I delved into frameworks more.

Comment: @Option I agree, frameworks like Bootstrap make like so much easier. No reason to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might I suggest the following code changes? I changed your statements into a loop, so that they are exact copies - easier to maintain this way, and harder to mess up simply typographically.

I also took out your in-line CSS, and put them in a `<style></style>` element, but I would suggest adding this to your CSS stylesheet if possible.

I also used [Heredocs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) instead of a doublequote string, as it allows you to have doublequotes in HTML elements without escaping them.

CSS:

```
<style>
    span {
         margin:auto;
         font-size:12px !important;
         color: #333638 !important;
    }
    #news-container {
          margin:auto;
          font-size:14px !important;
          text-align: center;
     }

     .centered{
          margin:auto; 
          text-align:center;
     }
</style>
```

PHP:

```
<?
    include 'db.php';
    $result     = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM status ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 9');
    $liElements = "";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $liElements .= <<<ELEMENT
            <li class="no-padding">
                <span>{$row['date']} {$row['type']}</span><br>
                {$row['person']} {$row['status']}
            </li>
ELEMENT;
    }
    $show_status = <<<NEWSCONTAINER
    <div class="no-padding" id="news-container">
        <ul class="no-padding">
            {$liElements}
        </ul>
    </div>
NEWSCONTAINER;
?>
```

Comment: And even if I echo the $show_status nothing is output?

Comment: No errors.  Checked debugging and no no errors either?

Comment: No, check it https://cheekytransport.co.uk/show_status5.php 
 and if you look at https://www.cheekytransport.co.uk/a11.php and you will see the problem my original issue.

Comment: I had a refactoring issue, try again with updated code

Comment: yes that works thanks, did you look at the original problem, its doing my head in big time

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help, I got it working when I added

```
span {
        margin:auto;
        font-size:12px !important;
        color: #333638 !important;
    }
    #news-container {
        margin:auto;
        font-size:14px !important;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .centered{margin:auto; text-align:center;}
```

That and the code from GrumpyCrouton seems to have done the trick, thankyou

Comment: Hi. I altered my answer to show what you put here as well, as it's the accepted answer

Comment: Thanks, I love the way you have made the code smaller, I have a similar code like the old one which would probably do with this sort of re-coding. I will try and edit your code to work with it!!! Anyway of showing you this directly??

Comment: Not really through StackOverflow as far as I know.

Comment: I have put my other query up here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45222480 Thanks if you can help