# Looking though results from mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql

having a previous issue sorted, it has occurred to me that I am wasting a lot of time effort because I am not using while loops properly, but I am struggling with them. I have this code here which I run 4 times for type_id=1,2,3,4 and then output the results into $vehicle1, $vehicles2, ect. Is there a way to run it to check how many type_id there is and then run through them all with the same output results as below?

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE type_id=1 AND verified='$yes' ORDER BY description");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$description = $row['description'];
$description = strtoupper($description);

$id = $row['id'];
$count++;
$vehicles1 .= "<a href=\"#entered-details\" onclick=\"$('#entered-details').show(); document.getElementById('vehicle_id').value='$id';document.getElementById('vehicle_list').value=''+document.getElementById('vehicle_list').value+'$id'+':';vehicle_selected.innerHTML = '$description';elt.tagsinput('add', { 'value': $id , 'text': '$description'   , 'type': '$type_id', 'type_id': '1'     });$('#show_new').show();\" class=\"btn new2 dodgerbluemenu\">$description</a>";
}
$vehicles1 .="<div><button id ='add_exec_button' type='button' class='btn btn-add-vehicles btn-danger'>Add executive vehicle</button></div>";
$vehicles1 .="<div style='margin-bottom: 5px'></div>";
```

Comment: Does this code work in it's current state?

Comment: Yes works fine, but from what you did earlier, I think I need to learn a bit about looping.

Comment: You are already using a loop here, but I'm looking over the code now to see if I can improve it.

Comment: I know, but use the same code 4 times just with different type_id. If I added another type_id I would have to add the code again, where as your method would load all type_id`s? This is where I am getting stuck, with the initial loop

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following;

```
<?

    $vehicles_array = array();

    $types = array(1,2,3,4);
    foreach($types as $value) {
        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE `type_id`='{$value}' AND `verified`='{$yes}' ORDER BY description");
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $description = strtoupper($row['description']);
            $id          = $row['id'];
            $vehicles1 .= <<<STRING
                <a href="" onclick="onClickAction('{$id}', '{$description}', '{$type_id}')" class="btn new2 dodgerbluemenu">{$description}</a>
STRING;
        }
        $vehicles1 .= " <div>
                            <button id='add_exec_button' type='button' class='btn btn-add-vehicles btn-danger'>Add executive vehicle</button>
                        </div>";
        $vehicles1 .= "<div style='margin-bottom: 5px'></div>";
        array_push($vehicles_array, $vehicles1);
    }
?>

<script>
    function onClickAction(id, description, type_id) {
        $('#entered-details').show(); 
        $('#vehicle_id').val(id);
        $('#vehicle_list').val($('#vehicle_list').val()+id+":");
        vehicle_selected.innerHTML = description;
        elt.tagsinput('add', { 'value': id , 'text': description, 'type': type_id, 'type_id': '1'});
        $('#show_new').show();
    }
</script>
```

The main thing I did here was add a `foreach` loop where you can specify as an array the values you'd like to check.

Also, you want to avoid inline javascript if possible, so I took out your inline javascript and put it in it's own function, I also changed your javascript from selecting things with javascript/jquery randomly to just using javascript.

You can access each vehicle link with the `$vehicles_array` array, by doing `$vehicles_array[0];` or 1, 2, 3, etc - or use a foreach loop to output each line with just a few lines of code (like 3 lines probably)

I may have missed something here because it's hard to tell what you actually need really, and this probably belongs more on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) more than StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that could be useful to you

```
        $my_types = [1,2,3,4];
        foreach($my_types as $type){
            $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE type_id=$type AND verified='$yes' ORDER BY description");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $description = $row['description'];
                $description = strtoupper($description);

                $id = $row['id'];
                $count++;
                $vehicles1 .= "<a href=\"#entered-details\" onclick=\"$('#entered-details').show(); document.getElementById('vehicle_id').value='$id';document.getElementById('vehicle_list').value=''+document.getElementById('vehicle_list').value+'$id'+':';vehicle_selected.innerHTML = '$description';elt.tagsinput('add', { 'value': $id , 'text': '$description'   , 'type': '$type_id', 'type_id': '1'     });$('#show_new').show();\" class=\"btn new2 dodgerbluemenu\">$description</a>";
            }
            $vehicles1 .="<div><button id ='add_exec_button' type='button' class='btn btn-add-vehicles btn-danger'>Add executive vehicle</button></div>";
            $vehicles1 .="<div style='margin-bottom: 5px'></div>";
        }
```

You could also make it so you get your types from your database, with this query :

```
SELECT id FROM types
```

Then just put the result in an array and loop through it.

Comment: This is a good start!  You'll want to use an array for `vehicles` if you aren't echoing the output within the loop.  Like `$vehicles[$i]` instead of `$vehicles1`

Comment: Thanks, will try but the $vehicles1 has to change to $vehicles2,3,4 etc when looping?

Comment: haha, I got that response as I sent that! Thank you I will try it

Comment: Like @BizzyBob said, you can put them in an array. `$vehicles[$type]`. After, you will be able to get the vehicles of type 1 with `$vehicles[1]`, 2 with `$vehicles[2]`, etc

Answer (score 0):

One loop and One query! Better than avoid loops is to avoid queries.

```
$result = mysqli_query( $con, "SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE verified='$yes' ORDER BY type_id ASC, description;"); // remove type_id here and add order

if( mysqli_num_rows( $result ) > 0 ) // Evaluate always, the notified too amount the execution time, display_errror=On in DEVEPOLMENT ENVIRONMENT
{
    $str_vehicles = "";
    $current_type_id = -1;
    $count = 0;

    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) )
    {
        if( $current_type_id != $row['type_id'] )
        {
            if( $current_type_id > -1 )
            {
                $str_vehicles .="<div><button id ='add_exec_button' type='button' class='btn btn-add-vehicles btn-danger'>Add executive vehicle</button></div>";
                $str_vehicles .="<div style='margin-bottom: 5px'></div>";
            }
            $current_type_id = $row['type_id'];
        }
        $id = $row['id'];
        $description = strtoupper( $row['description'] );
        $count++;
        $str_vehicles .= "<a href=\"#entered-details\" onclick=\"$('#entered-details').show(); document.getElementById('vehicle_id').value='$id';document.getElementById('vehicle_list').value=''+document.getElementById('vehicle_list').value+'$id'+':';vehicle_selected.innerHTML = '$description';elt.tagsinput('add', { 'value': $id , 'text': '$description', 'type': '$type_id', 'type_id': '1'     });$('#show_new').show();\" class=\"btn new2 dodgerbluemenu\">$description</a>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not output anything!